# Knockout to hold oldValue in obeservable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of reocrds fetching from the server, and converted to knockout observableArray by ko.mapping.fromJS.

```
      self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
      $.getJSON('/api/getdata', function(data) {
      var mappedTasks = $.map(dataFromServer, function(cls) {
                                 return ko.mapping.fromJS(cls);
                         });
         self.items(mappedTasks);
      }
```

In certain conditions I want some properties to be set as null and bind to the UI. Later upon users action I want to revert the old existing data instead of null. Is there way to attach a property oldValue to observable, so that I can preserve the old value and set it back when necessary.  Can knockout extend be used for holding the data?  Any help on this greatly appreciated,

George

Comment: See http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Comment: Its unclear to me if you mean you want all mapped observables to have this "cancel" ability and have conditions that null out certain values, or if certain conditions give this cancel ability to observables.

Comment: Its not the cancel ability that I am looking for, a way to attach some additional values to observable

Answer (score 0):

When you're mapping the data from the server to an object with knockout observables, you can also define additional observables on the same object.

```
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  $.getJSON('/api/getdata', function(data) {
  var mappedTasks = $.map(dataFromServer, function(cls) {
                             var item = ko.mapping.fromJS(cls);
                             item.AdditionalValue1 = ko.observable(0);
                             item.AdditionalValue2 = ko.observable('test');
                             return item;
                     });
     self.items(mappedTasks);
  }
```

If you would like to change the way the object that you're binding to is structured, it may be easier to build mapping from the server side data to your client side view model.